# FileSystemWatcher + Dialog

Tags: c#, multithreading

I wanna show a dialog everytime some file has been changed... But everytime that dialog shows up, my app freeze. How can I do this with another thread? Any ideas?

```
protected virtual void CreateWatcher (object path)
{
    if (watcher != null)
    {
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        watcher.Dispose ();
    }

    //Create a new FileSystemWatcher. 
    watcher = new FileSystemWatcher ();

    //Set the filter to only catch TXT files. 
    watcher.Filter = "*.txt";
    watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;

    //Subscribe to the Created event.
    watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler (OnChanged);
    watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler (OnChanged);
    //watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler (OnChanged);
    //watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler (OnRenamed);

    //Set the path to C:\\Temp\\ 
    watcher.Path = @path.ToString();

    //Enable the FileSystemWatcher events. 
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}
void OnChanged (object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    NovaInteracaoMsg();
    }

protected virtual void NovaInteracaoMsg ()
{
    novaInteracao = new MessageDialog (this, DialogFlags.DestroyWithParent, MessageType.Question, ButtonsType.YesNo, "Foi detectada a mudança nos arquivos do modelo. Deseja inserir uma nova interação?");
    ResponseType result = (ResponseType)novaInteracao.Run ();

    if (result == ResponseType.Yes) {
        OpenInfoWindow (novaInteracaoPath);
        return;
    }
    else {
        novaInteracao.Destroy ();
    }
}

void OnRenamed (object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
{
    //Console.WriteLine ("File: {0} renamed to\n{1}", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath);
    }

protected virtual void OpenInfoWindow (string path)
{
    ModMemory.Iteration iterWin = new ModMemory.Iteration (path);
    iterWin.Modal = true;
    iterWin.Show ();

    iterWin.Destroyed += delegate {
        // TODO: Funções para executar quando a janela for fechada
        // Possivelmente atualizar o número de interações realizadas
        Console.WriteLine ("Janela modal destruída");           
    };
}
```

Comment: That Dialog is what? MessageBox.Show ?

Comment: a little more detail, some code (maybe where the change is detected and the message box is displayed etc.) would be nice.

Comment: I´ve edited to show the code... sorry...

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you are already using another thread. Try one of the following approaches

1. Set the `FileSystemWatcher.SynchronizingObject` property so it
   raises events on your UI thread.  Now you can show a UI that won't
   freeze or
2. Use `Control.BeginInvoke()` in the event handler.

This was a psychic debugging attempt, there was nothing in your question that helped me be sure that's the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Call `Show()` instead of `ShowDialog()` in your form.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.show.aspx

**Edit** - MessageBox classes are Modal, if you want a modeless dialog window you'll have to create it yourself.